# list index out of range error when saving objects in admin after upgrade from Django 1.4 to 1.6

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-1.4, django-1.6

I have recently upgraded my 1.4 project to 1.6 and after working out some of the deprecation problems I have reached another one that I have not been able to solve.

Every time I either try to save a new object or edit an exisiting one I get a `list index out of range` error. I understand what the error means but don't know how django sets the value of the `obj` which is supposed to have a value at `obj[3]` The traceback sends me to here: `django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py in process_messages, line 38`

Full traceback:

```
   Traceback:
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  201.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/middleware.py" in process_response
  23.             unstored_messages = request._messages.update(response)
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/base.py" in update
  140.             messages = self._loaded_messages + self._queued_messages
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/base.py" in _loaded_messages
  91.             messages, all_retrieved = self._get()
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/fallback.py" in _get
  24.             messages, all_retrieved = storage._get()
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py" in _get
  70.         messages = self._decode(data)
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py" in _decode
  154.                     return json.loads(value, cls=MessageDecoder)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py" in loads
  339.     return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py" in decode
  49.         return self.process_messages(decoded)
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py" in process_messages
  41.             return [self.process_messages(item) for item in obj]
File "/Users/user/Development/virtual_environments/demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py" in process_messages
  38.                     print 'OBJECT 3: {0}'.format(obj[3])
```

Code from cookies.py. Problem is with trying to get `obj[3]`
The value of obj is: `[u'__json_message', 20, u'The Player "Goodman" was changed successfully.']`

```
class MessageDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):                            
    """                                                            
    Decodes JSON that includes serialized ``Message`` instances.   
    """                                                            

    def process_messages(self, obj):                               
        if isinstance(obj, list) and obj:                          
            if obj[0] == MessageEncoder.message_key:               
                if obj[1]:                                         
                    print obj                                      
                    print 'OBJECT 3: {0}'.format(obj[3])           
                    obj[3] = mark_safe(obj[3])                     
                return Message(*obj[2:])                           
            return [self.process_messages(item) for item in obj]   
        if isinstance(obj, dict):                                  
            return dict([(key, self.process_messages(value))       
                         for key, value in six.iteritems(obj)])    
        return obj                                                 

    def decode(self, s, **kwargs):                                 
        decoded = super(MessageDecoder, self).decode(s, **kwargs)  
        return self.process_messages(decoded)
```

Comment: The error means there is no 4th item in `obj`. The only person who can debug it is you. See what the value of obj is.

Comment: Django moved to native json library in 1.5. That might have broken it. Read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used

Comment: Yea I went through that page. I never used simplejson. The code above is djangos own code, not mine. I can save objects through shell and in other parts of my site but not in admin.

Comment: So it seems like my mistake was directly upgrading to 1.6. I removed django completely, installed 1.4 again, followed by 1.5 then 1.6. Now, no error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by a change in the "messages" cookie format, causing Django 1.6 not to be able to deserialize Django 1.4 message cookies.

Django 1.5 contains a fix that make it support both formats, but this fix is not (yet) present in in Django 1.6.

I've reported an [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22426) for this.

Meanwhile, you can use the following Middleware to remove old format cookies:

```
from django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie import CookieStorage
class FixMessageMiddleware(object):
    """
        The message cookie format has changed from Django 1.4 to
        Django 1.5. Django 1.5 probably supported both formats,
        but if you move from 1.4.x to 1.6.x directly, you will run into
        an IndexError:

        Exception Type: IndexError
        Exception Value:
        list index out of range
        Exception Location: (...) django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py in process_messages, line 37

        This small piece of middleware will track those cookies and destroy
        them (leaving new-style in tact)

        https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22426

        DISCLAIMER:
        This middleware will not attempt to rewrite the messages! You may
        miss important notifications because of this!
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        data = request.COOKIES.get("messages")
        storage = CookieStorage(request)
        try:
            storage._decode(data)
        except IndexError:
            del request.COOKIES['messages']
```

I've also [blogged](http://vanderwijk.info/blog/workaround-django-1-4-django-1-6-message-cookie-error/) about this problem (which is where the Middleware above comes from)